Why is this bolt's thread the way it is?
I scavenged an old bolt from an interior office remodel, and it is odd.
The thread appears to be triple-start BUT two of the three are milled off.
Shaft is 11.8mm and appears to be galvanised but the missing threads are shiny so appear to be trimmed after galvanising.
Pitch of threads is about 8.9 mm / turn to the same crest, so presumably 3.0 mm between adjacent crests if they were there.
There is a slight taper to the tip, and the threads also have a tapered lead-in.   The crest of the remaining thread seems to have intentional "divots" every 60 degrees for the first rotation, but they don't look like cutting teeth.
The head is a 6 sided hex with a flange.  The work was inside, so not exposed to any weather.
What is the purpose of this thread ?




that is for concrete

@jsotola That is the answer, with some more elaboration

Is this your bolt? https://www.alliedboltinc.com/product/1/2-inch-X-3-inch-CONCRETE-BOLT~7346

@KMJ Pretty much exactly that - want to post it as an answer ?

@KMJ no, that bolt is different ... the threads do not match

@jsotola both are concrete anchor bolts. There are actually a number of versions of them Tapcon, Simpson, Consert and others, all have their slight differences. I would have answered it myself, but I do not want to step on an answer given in the comment. All are merely screws driven into a precisely drilled hole in concrete.

@Criggie not sure I have anything else to add so I will upvote the other answer instead.

@Jack write your own answer ... don't worry about stepping on other answers ... yours may be better than mine ... mine is somewhat limited

@jsotola Nope, you got my vote.

It is a screw that cuts its own threads in concrete.
Drill a hole in concrete and then use a wrench to screw it in.
Follow the manufacturer's directions as to the diameter and depth of the hole.
Internet image search reveals that it is possibly an AM Premium Concrete Screw, because of the triple thread.

If you're going into concrete behind drylining (something these are very good for), better to use a nut driver than a wrench. Then you want pure torque rather than leverage to not chew up the plasterboard. A nut driver in a drill driver works well

@ChrisH these are exclusively for concrete, not plasterboard. Unless there is a use for them that I am not aware of?

@jay613 it's not about a surface coating. Where I've used them there's a gap of nearly an inch between the concrete and the plasterboard. This type take a bit of force to get going (some have more of a lead at the start). If you apply that force with a spanner you're pulling down against the hole in the soft plasterboard. I.e. the screw damages the plasterboard, the tool doesn't. You may be able to support the screw and stop this, but you may not have access or may be holding a bracket in place with the other hand

@jack "concrete behind drylining [plasterboard]" was what I said, snd exactly what I meant. The hole in the plasterboard can be oversized if you like, because the screw isn't meant to hold in it. It holds in the concrete.

@ChrisH I never heard of drylining, I had to look it up. Simply put, drywall applied over concrete walls and sometimes ceilings. I been in the trade for over 50 years and just learned something. I had done it before too, but with block (CMU) walls when there was no room to add firring to attach the drywall too.

And the threads are probably shiny because the concrete has rubbed the galvanization away.

@Jack it's a matter of both terminology and building styles
